# automatically running wine while double clicking .exe file on mac

Tags: macos, mac, wine

I have already had wine on my mac, now I would like to know whether it's possible to automatically running wine when I double-click an .exe file (on Finder), because I believe wine doesn't go to my Application folder when I installed it...

If possible, how exactly?

Added info: it's not as easy as `"Get Info"` --> `"Open With"` --> `"Other"` --> find wine (my case, in `/opt/local/bin/wine`) and select it, since it wasn't allowed (I believed because it wasn't recognized as an application)

PS: I don't know if this is needed, I use MacOSX Lion.

Comment: Link to @Zfm's SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336682/automatically-running-wine-while-double-clicking-exe-file-on-mac

Answer (score 2):

Give [wine bottler](http://winebottler.kronenberg.org/) a try. Sounds like it does what you want. Unfortunately couldn't try it myself.

Comment: This is good since it has wine.app on it... wine bottler is not needed since it will change my .exe file to .app file

Answer (score 1):

Check out WinOnX as another potential wine wrapper. It leaves your .exe files intact and lets you run them by double clicking.

http://www.winonx.com/

Comment: this might be better, but it's not free :D